# Cloning an Opportunity record

Tags: custom-button, developer, clone

I have successfully created a button that I am using for "renewing" an opportunity record. The custom button uses a URL hack to set certain values. One of the values it sets is putting the name of the Opportunity into a look-up field called "Previous Opportunity". This works great on the first pass.

The problem is when I want to "renew" the renewal. It looks as though the process is working, the URL even contains the name of the opportunity that it's supposed to, HOWEVER, when I save the record, the previous opportunity look-up somehow gets set back to the original record.

**For example:** I have Opportunity A. I renew Opportunity A and have a "cloned" version named Opportunity B. The previous opportunity field is set to Opportunity A. I go to renew Opportunity B. The is fine, it produces Opportunity C, with the previous opportunity set as Opportunity B, but when I save the record the previous opportunity lookup field is set back to Opportunity A.

Here is my button code:

```
/{!Opportunity.Id}/e?
clone=1&retURL=%2F{!Opportunity.Id}&00N600000037Qdt=1&opp11=Approved&opp10=
&opp9={!TODAY()}&00N60000002YSrx=
{!TODAY()}&00N60000002YeWq=&00N60000002YSsL=1&CF00N60000002YSsI=
{!Opportunity.Name}
```

Can anyone shed some light on what is going on and how to correct?

Thanks!

Comment: you are only passing the name of the oppty, you need to provide an id also to identify the right oppty you are trying to associate. I am guessing that you should get an error that says"multiple opptys found pick one" kind of a message when you save the oppty C. try adding &CF00N60000002YSsI_lkid={!Opportunity.id} this should fix your issue

Comment: I tried this, and nothing gets inserted into the field.